# Is the idea that God is infinite in all ways accepted by all Christians?

Tags: nature-of-god

From a Catholic site:

> "When we say that God is infinite, we mean that He is unlimited in every kind of perfection or that every *conceivable perfection belongs to Him in the highest *conceivable way."

*I presume this means 'conceivable by God' as infinity is, by definition, unable to be fully pictured by us.

This seems to imply that every single good thing (literally every good thing) is an aspect of God and is one of His many infinite attributes that has (again, literally) unending quality.

Do all Christians agree with this idea?

Comment: So all acknowledge God is all infinite good? That every kind of perfection exists as part of His being, to a never ending degree of quality?

Answer (score 3):

In short, no. Concepts such as infiniteness, omnipotence, ect do have slight variations among Christian theologians.

Alternative interpretation of the infiniteness of God:

Infinity is a pattern which is able to repeated endlessly. God contains characteristics and qualities- patterns- which will be repeated without end, such as His existence, goodness, and so on.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the Stacks Exchange! Although your answer is plausible, it can be greatly improved if you can list the sources with which you used to derive your answer or conclusion. If you happen to speak for your own denomination, please list your denomination here. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I am technically a Christian (leaning agnostic) and for my part am quite certain NOTHING which EXISTS is definable in way using infinity as a quantitative value.

At the risk of driving the conversation (answer I mean) into a no-man's land of tangential reference, it may of value to present an argument capable of rendering such questions impotent via means one might consider a bit unorthodox.  The intent here is to impart a (hopefully) useful methodology for such issues, for both question submitter and reader.

Briefly...referencing my views on the 'infinity' matters in the first sentence of this post, the key elements to note are 'existence', 'infinity', and 'quantitative'.  Existence may be defined as that which may be defined and described by some quantitative means such that the means used in the definition may be employed to describe the thing which 'exists' at any other time the object or thing may be determined to exist.

Assuming the above definition of existence is valid, the fact existence is explicitly dependent on quantitative description creates a situation which defies use of infinity by definition.  Using a simple example employing chemistry, an atom with 12 electrons and protons is always carbon.  The number 12 is useable as a single value.  Exactly how might one define an atom with an infinite number of electrons?  Try to determine the actual number of electrons for an infinite atom of this sort; of course it is impossible.

If God exists in any 'physical' sense, then God exists and is not exempt from the definition laid out above.  This may not be measurable by us, but that does not preclude the fact it still MUST be true.

If God is infinite or possesses ANYTHING of infinite value, even were some sort of mathematical proof leading in such a direction presented, the only conclusion one could make is that another frame of reference exists, wholly or partly undetectable by humans, in which these seemingly infinite values are measurable by some actual value.

As a final word, none of this has anything to do with my own religious beliefs or system of faith or in any way is a discussion of such.  Possessing a method to deal with (and actually make use of) a concept as slippery to comprehend as infinity, particularly to assist in weeding out the truth in matters of biblical context, is always worthwhile.

And so, to finally answer the question....no....not all Christians.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379/3961) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/3961) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon. *[This comment is only a welcome and not a comment on the quality of your post].*